# Why does this animation only work once?

Tags: ios, objective-c, core-animation, cabasicanimation

I have a UIView containing a UITapGestureRecognizer that triggers a method called `handleLeftTap`.

```
-(void)handleLeftTap {

    self.player.direction = LEFT;

    if(!self.isAnimating && self.toTile.isWalkable) {
        for(UIView *currentView in self.subviews) {
            CABasicAnimation *moveAnimation = [CABasicAnimation animationWithKeyPath:@"position"];
            [moveAnimation setDuration:MOVE_ANIMATION_DURATION];
            [moveAnimation setDelegate:self];
            [moveAnimation setRemovedOnCompletion:NO];
            [moveAnimation setFillMode:kCAFillModeForwards];
            moveAnimation.toValue = [NSValue valueWithCGPoint:CGPointMake(currentView.center.x+TILE_WIDTH, currentView.center.y)];
            [currentView.layer addAnimation:moveAnimation forKey:nil];
        }
        NSLog(@"animated\n");
    }
}
```

When I tap on the screen for the first time, this animation works perfectly; every subview moves to the right by `TILE_WIDTH` pixels. However, if I tap the screen again, the animation doesn't work at all; no view moves. I stepped through this code with breakpoints and verified that this animation is being added to the layers. It's just that the animation isn't being applied or something like that. Is there a way to fix this?

Comment: Does it make it past the if statement the second time?

Comment: @rdelmar - Yep. I placed a break point above the if statement to test that and it does indeed pass the if statement.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not quite sure, but are you sure that the second animation is a different location than the location after the first animation?

Comment: Thanks! I logged the positions of the views after the animation and it turned out I wasn't actually changing the view positions, merely animating the views to look like it. I fixed my code by putting `self.view.layer.position = finalPosition` type code in the `animationDidStop` method.